# Why does Twitter use -9999px instead of 0 for top/bottom values of their hero images?

Tags: html, css

*Why does Twitter use -9999px instead of 0 for top/bottom values of their hero images?*

```
top: -9999px;
bottom: -9999px;
```

It does look excatly the same as:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

It doesn't seem to be an accesssibility thing, as the hero image is shown and not hidden from the user.

*Is this some sort of CSS-trick that has a purpose?*

This is from the [CSS-Tricks' Twitter profile](https://twitter.com/Real_CSS_Tricks):

```css
.ProfileCanopy-headerBg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.ProfileCanopy-headerBg img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  margin: auto 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="ProfileCanopy-headerBg">
    <img alt="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/285019665/1399309574/1500x500" style="transform: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why they do it but it's bad practice as it's drawing a 9999px box behind the scenes - in this case that would be a 19998px box - may be something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317120/absolute-positioning-with-negative-top-left-right-bottom-for-image-stretching (using it for vertically centering)

Comment: dam pete beat me...: using it for vertically centering

Comment: I would go to say its just bad design... Im sure that look could have been achieved without all this non-sense

Comment: @Seabizkit But it is also centered vertically using `top: 0; bottom: 0;` as you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49mqunL9/

Comment: @lampshade you seem to be correct. I would say its just poor design/css but hey time is pressure... not everyone has the time to make things perfect and I'm sure the person is human and has other skills else where. trying to not discredit the guy who did it.. as maybe we don't understand and hes not here to defend himself... but i say the design could be changed and none of it would be needed.